# Why won't my .scss "code" take effect in my html page

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having a hard time understanding why my .scss file doesn't affect my html code.

SCSS Code:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap")
 
 
:root {
  --color-grey-dark: #202326;
  --color-green: #42b680;
  --color-purple: #7288da;
}
 
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
 
 
.test {
  background: var(--color-grey-dark);
  height: 100%;
  width: 72px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ url_for("static", filename="main.scss") }}>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
    <span>TEXT</span><br>
</div>
</body>
```

This is all test code btw.

I go to the page and it has no affect on the page.

I have made sure that it's actually finding the file too and I see 200 every time.

Also if it helps I'm using Python web-framework: Flask.

Comment: You need to compile SCSS to CSS before serving to a client browser

Comment: If you are using VS code use watch SASS extension in marketplace to compile sSCSS to CSS

Answer (score 0):

Change `filename="main.scss"` to `filename="main.css"`.  Browsers only understand CSS, not the SCSS it's compiled from.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semi colon `;` at the end of your google font import...

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap");
```

See fiddle here with semi colon included and `scss` compiled...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/5hmgx2t6/1/

Comment: Why Flask doesn't throw an error over this when compiling to CSS is beyond me...

Comment: I've had issues compiling google fonts css2 import url in sass using npm, could it be the `@` or `:` in the google css2 url? I had to revert to google css1 url, could not find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile SCSS to CSS before serving to a client site.

Please follow the official link to know more of sass :
https://sass-lang.com/guide